# Stanford POS tagger won't lemmatize pre-tokenized text

Tags: stanford-nlp, tokenize, lemmatization, pos-tagger

I'd like to lemmatize and POS tag text according to the [FAQ](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/pos-tagger-faq.shtml#pretagged). This command provided in the FAQ works correctly:

```
$ java -cp "*:lib/*" edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger \
    -model models/english-left3words-distsim.tagger \
    -textFile samsawme.txt -outputFormat inlineXML \
    -outputFormatOptions lemmatize -sentenceDelimiter newline
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<pos> 
<sentence id="0"> 
<word wid="0" pos="NNP" lemma="Sam">Sam</word> 
<word wid="1" pos="VBD" lemma="see">saw</word> 
<word wid="2" pos="PRP" lemma="I">me</word> 
<word wid="3" pos="." lemma=".">.</word> 
</sentence> 
</pos>
```

However, if I add the `-tokenize false` flag, and use instead a tokenized version of the text file, the lemmas disappear from the XML file:

Contents of `samsawme_tokenized.txt`:

```
Sam saw me .
```

Command:

```
$ java -cp "*:lib/*" edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger \
    -model models/english-left3words-distsim.tagger \
    -textFile samsawme_tokenized.txt -outputFormat inlineXML \
    -outputFormatOptions lemmatize -sentenceDelimiter newline \
    -tokenize false # !!!
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pos>
<sentence id="0">
  <word wid="0" pos="NNP">Sam</word>
  <word wid="1" pos="VBD">saw</word>
  <word wid="2" pos="PRP">me</word>
  <word wid="3" pos=".">.</word>
</sentence>
</pos>
```

Is there any workaround to including lemmas when tagging pre-tokenized but not necessarily lemmatized text?